# Will my ceiling hold an over the popcorn solution?

Tags: truss, popcorn

I am looking for a solution to my popcorn without removing it. I am thinking of using MDF ship-lap then creating small depth coffers.

My issue is that I don't know how much weight my ceiling can hold. It's vaulted ceiling made of 2X4 trusses on a 24" OC. I when to the attic and counted 12 trusses over the area i am concerned about. The area is about 26.25' wide (*measuring across the trusses*), the peak in the living space is about 13' and the length of each angle (*along the trusses*) to the peak is about 16.3'.

What's on the ceiling now is SR but I don't know how thick it is. I do have a fireplace in the middle of the room and I have no idea if that is supporting anything.

[image]

Comment: OK... you don't like the fad popcorn ceiling but you want to spent a crapload of time putting up crappy mdf shiplap.   I am going to give you a friendly slap upside the head to save you your sanity - just no don't do it.   (mdf for a ceiling?  shiplap?... holy cow)  Not to mention that you can't install stuff on popcorn ceiling flat.   Hence the popcorn ceiling.   I have done lots of dumb design things - just trying to help.

Comment: If the popcorn in not painted over then just scrape it off. Messy but not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If, after some more thought, the MDF is not an option, you could install new drywall sheets over the popcorn. It does require mudding/taping, which is perhaps what you are trying to avoid.

Double drywall ceilings are not uncommon and not as heavy as MDF. For backing you can install resilient channel or 1x3 / 1x4 strapping across the joists.

Alternatively you could install 1x5 T&G cedar (much lighter than MDF), fastened with finishing nails to strapping. No mudding and no drywall lift.

Answer (score 0):

I do ***believe*** your ceiling would support the added weight of the shiplap. For an actual confirmation ***you really need to *consult an engineer or possibly a truss manufacturer****  who can run the calculations for the additional weight you intend to add.

I do not see going directly over the popcorn with your shiplap. If you really insist on leaving it, then perhaps attach a flat 2x4 (preferable) or 1x4 screwed to the bottom chord of the trusses and attach your shiplap to that. It seems a tongue and groove would be better than a shiplap- with the addition of construction glue you could blind nail the T&G.

Truthfully, the removal of the popcorn seems an easier/ cleaner option.The un-eveness and the length of fastener necessary to soundly attach the shiplap seem likely to cause more difficulty than removing the popcorn.

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part about removing popcorn ceilings is in having to move and/or cover all of your furniture and carpets first. You would pretty much have to do that to install the alternatives too, so why not just get rid of the stuff?

Comment: Asbestos.  Some popcorn had asbestos in it.  Take a small sample to a local asbestos lab, have them look at it under a microscope for about $50, and be sure you're not contaminating the entire house.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that a home with modern engineered trusses also has asbestos ceiling texture.

Comment: If you wet it down it comes off easier and helps to mitigate problems with asbestos dust.